# System access violation error in listpicker Wp8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am getting an error in selection Changed event of listpicker whenever accessing the seleceted item from the picker
Code:

```
private void AppNamePicker_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ListPicker picker = sender as ListPicker;

    if (picker.SelectedItem.ToString()!="---Select---")
    {
           MessageBox.Show(picker.SelectedItem.ToString());
     }

}
```

Comment: can you share full code with xaml

Comment: Please post full code block and xaml code.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely because your `ListPicker.SelectedItem` is `null`.  Check that first before you try to do any actions on it.  The `SelectionChanged` will fire regardless if you have any items in the ListPicker on `Loaded`.

```C#
private void AppNamePicker_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ListPicker picker = sender as ListPicker;
    if (picker.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        if (picker.SelectedItem.ToString() != "---Select---")
        {
            MessageBox.Show(picker.SelectedItem.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```